# What are all the possible ways to link an external CSS file with my HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to link an external CSS file with a HTML page but it does not work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\bootstrap\cssbootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value=Submit>
    </body>
</html>
```

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't use the full path on your hard drive. Use the path relative to your web root.

Comment: Thank you ,But I have bootstrap css in my d: drive

Comment: make sure you have all related file in one main folder, then use relative path

Comment: Instead of pointing out what you;re still doing wrong, take the advice you asked for and fix it.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Arun Kumar and John Conde i got solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not specify a Windows-style path in `href` attributes.

You can use the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) to specify paths to local files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///D:/bootstrap/cssbootstrap.min.css">
```

Also, you can always use [directory traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) with dots and slahes:

- `.`  this location
- `..` up a directory
- `../` the parent of the current directory
- `./` the current directory
- `/` the root of the current

So if there’s a Bootstrap folder in your WWW root, this will work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/cssbootstrap.min.css">
```

Finally, [according to the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-link-href), the `href` attribute…

> <sup><sub>( … )</sub></sup> must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces

If you are *really* interested in all the possible ways, see [the W3C spec on valid URLs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-non-empty-url-potentially-surrounded-by-spaces).

Answer (score 0):

You've got most of it right, but I don't think you picked the right path to the your css folder. Enter the folder your html is in, then go and add the Css file to the same folder. 
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssbootstrap.min.css">`
Change your link tag into that and it should work.

If you're still having problems try giving this page a go http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

locate your css files in the folder in which your html file s located.
 Then Try Like The following,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```